# urllib2 as parser for wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, urllib2

I want to get a web page through a http proxy and view it in wxpython, using SetPage.

```
import wx
import wx.html
import urllib2
class MyHtmlFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, size=(600,400))
    proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1:3166'})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com')
    page = response.read().decode("UTF-8")
    response.close()        
    html = wx.html.HtmlWindow(self)
    html.SetPage(page)

app = wx.App()
frm = MyHtmlFrame(None, "Simple HTML Browser")
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I can get the page content now if i print out page. but i get an error in html.SetPage(page)

Comment: html.SetPage(page)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\html.py", line 988, in SetPage
    return _html.HtmlWindow_SetPage(*args, **kwargs)
PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "strcmp(setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL), "C") == 0" failed at ..\..\src\common\intl.cpp(1449) in wxLocale::GetInfo(): You probably called setlocale() directly instead of using wxLocale and now there is a mismatch between C/C++ and Windows locale.
Things are going to break, please only change locale by creating wxLocale objects to avoid this!

Comment: You should add that traceback to your question. Have you called `setlocale()` in your code? (assuming there is more code than you've shown)

Comment: There is no more code

Comment: Try calling `wxSetLocale(LC_ALL, NULL)` if there is such a thing. This answer might help otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24763770/21945

Answer (score 0):

The `HtmlWindow` widget is pretty limited in what it can display. I would highly recommend using wxPython's `WebView` widget instead for viewing websites:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html

WebView uses Trident as its backend on Windows and Webkit elsewhere, so it shouldn't have any issues displaying web pages.

Comment: Thanks i will look into using that.Im guessing that HtmlWindow Only has the capability to display post source or a pre defined html string..

Comment: It's pretty limited. I don't think it does JS or CSS at all, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses and help. 
I managed to get a page to load it was the encoding of the html i believe.

```
  page.decode("UTF-8)
```

Solved the problem in the line

```
dialog.browser.SetPage(page.decode("UTF-8"),"")
```

Using Browser now instead of html.HtmlWindow

```
        class MyBrowser(wx.Dialog):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
                wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
                sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
                self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
                sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10)
                self.SetSizer(sizer)
                self.SetSize((800, 700))

        dialog = MyBrowser(None, -1)
        dialog.browser.SetPage(page.decode("UTF-8"),"")
        dialog.Show()
```

Comment: Not that it matters that much, but how is this different than my answer?

Comment: the page needed decoding that was the only difference ;)

Comment: Whoops...I missed that somehow. Thanks!