# Using wxpython with Mayavi for UI, throws error in file "decorated_scene.py"

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I was running a python program that uses Mayavi for 3D display of georeferenced DEM(Digital Elevation Model). It runs perfectly fine in Anaconda environment. But when running on windows, it requires PyQt/PySide/wxpython to be installed for UI (to display the 3D model).

On running the code, it began throwing this error

```
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "strcmp(setlocale(0, 0), "C") == 0" failed at ..\..\src\common\intl.cpp(1694) in wxLocale::GetInfo(): You probably called setlocale() directly instead of using wxLocale and now there is a mismatch between C/C++ and Windows locale.
Things are going to break, please only change locale by creating wxLocale objects to avoid this!
```

I referred [this 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234843/how-to-set-python-default-locale-on-windows) and [this 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444951/wxpython-3-0-breaks-older-apps-locale-error) to solve this error by including the following at the beginning of the code

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'C')
```

There was another error too. This error was due to a command `m.set_outline_color(1,1,1)` which is incompatible with current version of wx, in the file *C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tvtk\pyface\ui\wx\**decorated_scene.py***

The Error:

```
D:\supriya\CODES_ALL>python 3D_Mayavi_Interactive_Plot.py
wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3D_Mayavi_Interactive_Plot.py", line 286, in <module>
    surf = mlab.surf(data, color=(1,1,1), warp_scale=0.5) #
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\helper_functions.py", line 38, in the_function
    return pipeline(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\helper_functions.py", line 78, in __call__
    scene = tools.gcf().scene
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\figure.py", line 117, in gcf
    return figure(engine=engine)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\figure.py", line 69, in figure
    engine.new_scene(name=name, size=size)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\apptools\scripting\recordable.py", line 48, in _wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\engine.py", line 452, in new_scene
    viewer = self.scene_factory(**factory_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\ui\mayavi_scene.py", line 89, in viewer_factory
    viewer.open()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyface\i_window.py", line 203, in open
    self._create()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyface\ui\wx\application_window.py", line 125, in _create
    contents = self._create_contents(self.control)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tvtk\tools\ivtk.py", line 406, in _create_contents
    self.scene = self._scene_factory(parent)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\ui\mayavi_scene.py", line 68, in mayavi_scene_factory
    s = MayaviScene(parent, stereo=p['stereo'])
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tvtk\pyface\ui\wx\decorated_scene.py", line 70, in __init__
    self._setup_axes_marker()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tvtk\pyface\ui\wx\decorated_scene.py", line 127, in _setup_axes_marker
    self._background_changed(self.background)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tvtk\pyface\ui\wx\decorated_scene.py", line 204, in _background_changed
    m.outline_color(0,0,0)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "GetEventHandler() == this" failed at ..\..\src\common\wincmn.cpp(470) in wxWindowBase::~wxWindowBase(): any pushed event handlers must have been removed
```

The solution is in the answer below:

Answer (score 1):

Open *C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tvtk\pyface\ui\wx\**decorated_scene.py***.

Find this line `m.set_outline_color(1,1,1)` and replace it with `m.outline_color = (1,1,1)`

And Done!

*This is my first post on stack overflow in QnA format. If there's anything I should improvise upon do guide me.*